# How to align equations with integrals and "subject to" equations

Tags: equations, align

I have a long expression (maximization problem) which I force down to the next line using `//`.

I also have two functions ("subject to") which I want to place underneath. I use `&` to make the expressions fit vertically.

**Problem**:

- The third integral expression which I have to force down looks weird and isn't aligned with the two integral expression above. I don't know how to fix it.
- The alignment is off. Fx "Another equation here" should be aligned with `Max(n_G, 0) \leq n_{min} \leq Min(n_B,1)`. Using `&` obviously doesn't solve the problem.
- Extra: The reason I use `\def\mclimits_#1{\limits_{\mathclap{#1}}}` is to make the long expression `n_{min}` fit in the limits of the integral.

**Code**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\def\mclimits_#1{\limits_{\mathclap{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\underset{n_{min}}{\text{argmax}} 
& & \Pi = \frac{1}{M}\[
\int\mclimits_{n_{min}}^M\! n_cP_c\, \mathrm{d}n_c
\] + \frac{p}{M}\[
\int\mclimits_{n_B}^M\! \delta\bigg(z\beta P_r\big(h(1-n_B)+(1-h)x_B\big)-D\bigg)\, \mathrm{d}n_c
\] \\
& & + \frac{1-p}{M}\[
\int\mclimits_{n_{min}}^M\! \delta\bigg(z\beta P_r\big(h(1-n_B)+(1-h)x_G\big)-D\bigg)\, \mathrm{d}n_c
\]  \\
\text{subject to}
& & Max(n_G, 0) \leq n_{min} \leq Min(n_B,1)\\
& &  \text{Another equation here}\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

**Current output**:

[image]

Comment: Please make your example compilable. I get errors.

Comment: Hmm, I ran it. I get errors too. But it compiles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your MWE has errors: you nested equation (`\[ ... \]`) in equation ... I try to figured out what is your problem. After cleaning of your code I obtain the following results:

[image]

Is this what you looking for? In your code I also added a `split` environment for the long first equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax} 

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\argmax_{n_{\min}}\Pi
    & = \frac{1}{M}\int\limits_{n_{\min}}^M\! n_cP_c\, \mathrm{d}n_c \\
    &\qquad   + \frac{p}{M}\int\limits_{n_B}^M\delta\bigg(z\beta P_r\big(h(1-n_B) + 
                (1-h)x_B\big)-D\bigg)\, \mathrm{d}n_c \\
    &\qquad   + \frac{1-p}{M}\int\limits_{n_{\min}}^M 
                \delta\bigg(z\beta P_r\big(h(1-n_B) + (1-h)x_G\big)-D\bigg)\, \mathrm{d}n_c
      \end{split}                                           \\
\text{subject to}
        &\ \max(n_G, 0) \leq n_{min} \leq \min(n_B,1)      \notag  \\
        &  \text{Another equation here}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Thanks to @egreg for the improvements he suggested in his comment.

Comment: Yes :) `Split` works great!  I just removed `\\ &\qquad` between the first and second integral expression to place them on the same line, like in the original code. Just one small thing: Why is "Another equation here" slightly more to the left than the expression just above?

Comment: Because for expression above is shifted after ampersand to the right with `\ `. (otherwise it sticks with text before it). I assume that there  ones wild be real equation, then this shift will looks slightly different.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, will be replaced with a real equation. Thx again!

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{argmax}` will allow typing `\argmax_{n_{\min}\Pi` instead of that awful concoction.

Comment: @egreg, yes, this is correct approach. I will consider this in eddit of my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure, if I got your right. Like this?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\argmax}{argmax}
\def\mclimits_#1{\limits_{\mathclap{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext  
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
        \underset{n_{\min}}{\argmax}(\Pi) &= \frac{1}{M}\int\mclimits_{n_{\min}}^M n_c P_c\, \mathrm{d}n_c \\
        &\quad+ \frac{p}{M}\int\mclimits_{n_B}^M \delta\Bigl(z\beta P_r\bigl(h(1-n_B)+(1-h)x_B\bigr)-D\Bigr)\, \mathrm{d}n_c \\
        &\quad+ \frac{1-p}{M}
        \int\mclimits_{n_{\min}}^M \delta\Bigl(z\beta P_r\bigl(h(1-n_B)+(1-h)x_G\bigr)-D\Bigr)\, \mathrm{d}n_c
    \end{split}
        \shortintertext{subject to}
        &\max(n_G, 0) \leq n_{\min} \leq \min(n_B,1)\\
        &\text{Another equation here}
\end{align} 
\blindtext  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, looks good :)

Comment: +1 for using `\intertext`.

Answer (score 4):

With ConTeXT MKIV

```
\setupmathlabeltext[argmax=argmax]
\definemathcommand[argmax][limop]{\mfunctionlabeltext{argmax}}
\starttext
\placeformula
\startformula
  \startmathalignment
    \NC \argmax_{n_{\min}}\Pi
    \NC = \frac{1}{M}\int\limits_{n_{\min}}^M\! n_cP_c\, \diff n_c \NR
    \NC\NC\quad + \frac{p}{M}\int\limits_{n_B}^M\delta\bigg(z\beta P_r\big(h(1-n_B) + (1-h)x_B\big)-D\bigg)\, \diff n_c \NR
    \NC\NC\qquad + \frac{1-p}{M}\int\limits_{n_{\min}}^M \delta\bigg(z\beta P_r\big(h(1-n_B) + (1-h)x_G\big)-D\bigg)\, \diff n_c \NR[+]
    \startintertext
      subject to
    \stopintertext
    \NC \max(n_G, 0) \NC \leq n_{\min} \leq \min(n_B,1) \NR
    \NC              \NC \text{Another equation here} \NR[+]
  \stopmathalignment  
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: What `\quad` in one line and `\qquad` in the other; won't `\quad` on both lines look better (aligned `+` signs)

Comment: @Aditya This is a matter of taste, I guess.  One could also leave out the horizontal space altogether to have `=` and `+` aligned.  I'll leave it there, because I like it that way, but your proposed layout would look good as well.  May the user decide.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `geometry` package, you have more sensible margins and it looks  nicer with `alignat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\argmax}{argmax}
\def\mclimits_#1{\limits_{\mathclap{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
    & \argmax_t{n_{\min}}(\Pi) &&=\!\begin{aligned}[t]\frac{1}{M}\int\mclimits_{n_{\min}}^M n_c P_c\, \mathrm{d}n_c + \frac{p}{M}\int\mclimits_{n_B}^M \delta\Bigl(z\beta P_r\bigl(h(1-n_B)+(1-h)x_B\bigr)-D\Bigr)\, \mathrm{d}n_c & \\
  + \frac{1-p}{M} \int\mclimits_{n_{\min}}^M \delta\Bigl(z\beta P_r\bigl(h(1-n_B)+(1-h)x_G\bigr)-D\Bigr)\, \mathrm{d}n_c &
  \end{aligned}\\
  & \text{subject to} \quad\mathrlap{\max(n_G, 0) \leq n_{\min} \leq \min(n_B,1)} \notag\\[1.5ex]
  & \rlap{Another equation here}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you mentioned before that this is due to your editor, but there are a lot of Unicode characters creeping into your answer, e.g. `Π`, `β`, and `δ`.  Of course this would work if you used a Unicode engine in conjunction with `unicode-math`, but not with classic pdfTeX.

Comment: Oh! yes. When it's late, I may forget to check. Thanks for pointing it! Hope it's all fixed now.

Comment: BTW: Which editor are you using?

Comment: WinEdt. I wrote a small package for it that does some sort of pretty-printing in order to have a an easier-to-understand displayed code in formulae (Greek letters, numerical exponents, a number of symbols).